# Porque mi ventana modal queda debajo del footer?

Tags: html, jquery, .net, script

Tengo mi diseño web con **Masterpage** la cual contiene el **menu** y el **footer**. En la vista **Index**, tengo mi ventana **Modal** la cual al darle clic aparece debajo del Footer, este es el html de mi Masterpage:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <!-- Header -->
     <header id="header">
     <!-- Aquí todo mi menu... -->
     </header>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <!-- Footer Wrapper -->
        <footer id="footer" class="container">
        <div class="row 200%">
                    <div class="3u 12u(mobile)">
                            <!-- Links -->
                        <section>
                            <h2>servicios y estilos</h2>
                            <div>
                                <p>Asesoramiento en Decoración</p>
                                <p>Artista Plástico</p>
                                <p>Enchapado en Acero</p>
                                <p>Poliuretano Parafinico</p>
                                <p>Duco</p>
                                <p>Laminado en pan de oro y plata</p>
                                <p>Poliéster Acrílico</p>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    <!-- Este es el Html del Index -->
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

        <!-- Main Wrapper -->
        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper style1">
                <div class="inner">
                    <!-- Feature 1 -->
                    <section class="container box feature1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <header class="first major">
                                    <%--<h2>This is an important heading</h2>--%>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <article class="thumb">
                                                <section>
                                                    <img id="id1" class="popup" src="images/arte (1).JPG" alt="Cuadro de flores, hecho a base de óleo" width="300" height="200" style="border-radius: 20px;">
                                                    <h3>cuadro de flores</h3>
                                                    <p>hecho a base de óleo</p>
                                                </section>
                                            </article>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <img id="id2" class="popup" src="images/arte (2).JPG"" alt="Cuadro abstracto - pilares, con marco marrón" width="300" height="200" style="border-radius: 20px;" />
                                                <h3>cuadro abstracto - pilares</h3>
                                                <p>con marco marrón</p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="4u 12u(mobile)">
                                            <section>
                                                <img id="id3" class="popup" src="images/arte (3).JPG"" alt="Cuadro abstracto, con marco paspartú" width="300" height="200" style="border-radius: 20px;" />
                                                <h3>cuadro abstracto</h3>
                                                <p>con marco paspartú</p>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- AQUÍ LA VENTANA MODAL -->
                                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                        <span class="close">Cerrar</span>
                                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="#" />
                                        <div id="caption"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <section>
                                        <a href="GaleriaFotos.aspx" class="button icon fa-arrow-circle-o-right">Ver mas</a>
                                    </section>
                                </header>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Esta bien, aqui dejo el link de mi CSS referenciado en la masterpage [main.css](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kr84ZHD4CzuSO2wrX4fuJx66AQjiwPOJ/view?usp=sharing) y el estilo del Modal lo ubico directo en el head la masterpage, cabe mencionar que cuando trabajo sin Masterpage no tengo este problema:**

**Aqui el Html, Css y Js del Modal:**

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var images = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            modalImg.alt = this.alt;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
    }
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    modal.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
        #mask iframe {
            border-radius: 10%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 50;
            border: 10px solid #e2ffa4;
        }

        #popup {
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

            #popup:hover {
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            /*overflow: auto;*/ /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content (image) */
        .modal-content {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
        }

        /* Caption of Modal Image */
        #caption {
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 700px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            height: 150px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-family: impact;
            color: #000;
            background: #DA251D;
            line-height: 70%;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #fff, 1px -1px 0px #fff, -1px 2px 0px #fff, 1px 1px 0px #fff;
            -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
            animation-name: zoom;
            animation-duration: 0.6s;
        }

        /* Add Animation */
        .modal-content {
            -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
            animation-name: zoom;
            animation-duration: 0.6s;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
            border: 0px solid #000000;
            Copiar texto;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
            from {
                -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            }

            to {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
        @keyframes zoom {
            from {
                transform: scale(0);
            }

            to {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            position: center;
            top: 90px;
            right: 35px;
            color: #ccc;
            font-size: 25px;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #f00;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        /* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            .modal-content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                        <span class="close">Cerrar</span>
                                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="#" />
                                        <div id="caption"></div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir algo más de información (un pantallazo, el CSS completo, código js, etc.)? He probado con tu HTML así tal cual y se ve bien pero me falta, sobre todo, el CSS.

Comment: Si, sobre todo se necesitan los css, porque claramente pareciera ser un problema de estilos, se tiene que verificar que la ventana modal tenga un z-index por ejemplo, pero vamos a mencionar supuestos, porque falta información

Comment: Esta bien, ya agregué las referencias adicionales, gracias. ;)

Comment: Pues yo lo sigo viendo bien... https://imgur.com/a/FD99D

Comment: si efectivamente, el código si trabaja bien, el detalle esta en que el footer sale sobre el modal al bajar con el scroll.